# Плавное увеличение/уменьшение объекта. OpenGl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, анимация, opengl

**C#+OpenGl**

шарик:

```
     void DrawCircle(int radcir)
    {
        gr.FillEllipse(fig2, 300, 170, radcir, radcir);
        gr.DrawEllipse(p2, 300, 170, radcir, radcir);

    }
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку рисуется шарик, который должен менять размер, увеличиваться и уменьшаться.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();   

        fon = new SolidBrush(Color.MediumSeaGreen);
        p2 = new Pen(Color.LightSlateGray);
        fig2 = new SolidBrush(Color.OrangeRed);

        radcir = 50;
        DrawCircle(radcir);

    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать. Возможно как-то с помощью таймера или масштабирования ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут кажется слегка увлёкся...

Но здесь есть ответ на твой вопрос и возможно на пару следующих хд Зачем такой огород? Потому что при простом засовывание кода в стандартный обработчик FormPaintEvent для каждой перерисовки круга, придётся вызывать свойство Form.Refresh() которое помимо твоего кружка, перерисовывает всю форму. Почему нельзя было просто отправить Graphics в функцию отрисовки, зачем эти делегаты и коллбэки? Можно, я просто показал другой способ) Зачем классы и длиннокод? Это спасает код от каши, сейчас круги можно быстро перенести на любую форму, кругов можно создать сколько хочешь и для их отрисовки требуется вызвать всего лишь одну функцию

**UPD**
Что бы избавится от любых морганий можно создать битмап с размерами окна

```cs
Bitemap yourBitemap = new Bitemap(this.width, this. height)
```

получить его Graphics

```cs
Graphics.FromImage(yourBitemap);
```

отрисовывать всё в нём, а в конце просто делать

```cs
this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(yourBitmap, new Point(0, 0))
```

Что-бы скомпилировать, создай новый проект с классическим Windows Forms и замени весь код Form1.cs на этот:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PlaygroundCS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button upButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button downButton;


        /// <summary>
        /// Структура описывающая данные и методы необходимые для построения круга
        /// </summary>
        class CCircle
        {
            //Делегаты описывающие шаблон функций Graphics.FillElipse() и Graphics.DrawEllipse которые будут передаваться для обратного вызова
            public delegate void solidEllipseDrawCallback( SolidBrush brush, int coord1, int coord2, int rad1, int rad2 );
            public delegate void emptyEllipseDrawCallback(        Pen pen  , int coord1, int coord2, int rad1, int rad2 );

            //А это делегат описывающий шаблон функции для события
            public delegate void drawAllCircleEventHandler(solidEllipseDrawCallback body, emptyEllipseDrawCallback border);

            //Событие которое будет вызывать обработку всех кругов при отрисовке
            private static event drawAllCircleEventHandler DrawAllCircleEvent;

            //Публичние свойства обеспечивающие доступ к локальным переменным
            public float Radius       { get { return this.radius; }        set { this.radius = value; } }
            public Point Coordinate { get { return coordinate; }    set { coordinate = value; } }


            //Переменные хранящие текущие параметры круга
            private float radius;
            SolidBrush  innerColor; 
            Pen         borderColor;

            Point coordinate;

            //Конструктор структуры
            public CCircle(  int radius,
                           Point coordinate )
            {
                this.radius = radius;

                innerColor  = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                borderColor = new Pen(Color.Black,3f);

                this.coordinate = coordinate;

                //Добавление каждого нового шара в событие при создание
                DrawAllCircleEvent += Draw;
            }

            //Другой конструктор структуры
            public CCircle(  int radius,
                      SolidBrush innerColor, 
                             Pen borderColor,
                           Point coordinate )
            {
                this.radius = radius;

                this.innerColor     = innerColor;
                this.borderColor    = borderColor;

                this.coordinate = coordinate;

                //Добавление каждого нового шара в событие при создание
                DrawAllCircleEvent += Draw;
            }


            //Функция отрисовки круга (принимает в качестве аргументов ссылки на функции, которые подходят под шаблон на верху)
            public void Draw(solidEllipseDrawCallback body,
                             emptyEllipseDrawCallback border)
            {
                //Обратный вызов переданных функций
                body  ( innerColor, Coordinate.X, Coordinate.Y, (int)Radius, (int)Radius);
                border(borderColor, Coordinate.X, Coordinate.Y, (int)Radius, (int)Radius);
            }


            public static void DrawAll(solidEllipseDrawCallback body,
                                emptyEllipseDrawCallback border)
            {
                //Вызываем событие коллективной обработки кругов
                DrawAllCircleEvent.Invoke(body, border);
            }
            static void OnPaint(object OnPaint, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
                DrawAll(e.Graphics.FillEllipse, e.Graphics.DrawEllipse);
            }
            public static void addDrawHandler(Form frm)
            {
                frm.Paint += OnPaint;
            }
        }


        //Создаём массив из экземпляров структуры описанной выше (я не знаю, зачем нам столько кругов, честно)
        CCircle[] circles = { new CCircle(100, new Point(100,20)),
                             new CCircle(30,  new Point(190, 80)),
                             new CCircle(200, new Point(70, 150)) };



        //Загрузка формы:
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Включение двойной буфферизации графического окна (убирает мерцание экрана при очистках)
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            downButton.MouseDown += DownButton_MouseDown;
            downButton.MouseUp += DownButton_MouseUp;

            upButton.MouseDown += UpButton_MouseDown;
            upButton.MouseUp += UpButton_MouseUp;

            CCircle.addDrawHandler(this);
        }

        //==============================================================================================

        //   НИЖЕ НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННО КОД ДЕМОНСТРИРУЮЩИЙ ПЛАВНОЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЙ И РАБОТУ С КНОПКАМИ

        //==============================================================================================


        //Если true -- идёт процесс изменения размера кругов
        bool isScaling = false;


        //Обработчик события нажатия нижней кнопки
        private void UpButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics my_gph = this.CreateGraphics();

            isScaling = true;

            while(isScaling)
            {
                circles[0].Radius += 0.1f;
                circles[1].Radius += 0.2f;
                circles[2].Radius -= 0.1f;

                my_gph.Clear(Color.Black);
                CCircle.DrawAll(my_gph.FillEllipse, my_gph.DrawEllipse);

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        //Обработчик события отпускания нижней кнопки
        private void DownButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isScaling = false;
        }

        //Обработчик события нажатия верхней кнопки
        private void DownButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics my_gph = this.CreateGraphics();

            isScaling = true;

            while (isScaling)
            {
                circles[0].Radius -= 0.1f;
                circles[1].Radius -= 0.2f;
                circles[2].Radius += 0.1f;

                my_gph.Clear(Color.Black);
                CCircle.DrawAll(my_gph.FillEllipse, my_gph.DrawEllipse);

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        //Обработчик события отпускания верхней кнопки
        private void UpButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isScaling = false;
        }








        //Настройки формы и кнопок
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.upButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.downButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1115, 798);
            this.Controls.Add(this.downButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.upButton);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

            // 
            // upButton
            // 
            this.upButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.upButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1014, 127);
            this.upButton.Name = "upButton";
            this.upButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(89, 76);
            this.upButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.upButton.Text = "Тык";
            this.upButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // downButton
            // 
            this.downButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.downButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1014, 209);
            this.downButton.Name = "downButton";
            this.downButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(89, 76);
            this.downButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.downButton.Text = "Тык";
            this.downButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью таймера? Когда нажимаем на кнопку например "Запустить" и шарик увеличивается до определенного размера а затем начинает уменьшаться тоже до определенного размера и тд и через определенный интервал времени?Просто надо именно как-то так(

Comment: Замените событие отпускания кнопки на событие срабатывания таймера. Как только isScaling примет значение false цикл изменения размера прервётся. А по нажатию кнопки тогда дополнительно запускайте таймер перед началом цикла

Comment: Аналогично можно вызывать функцию уменьшения в конце работы таймера и перезапускать его. Можно добавить ещё одну булевую переменную, которая обозначала бы направление и в конце просто сделать:  `isReverce = !isReverce; if (isReverse) { UpButton_MouseDown(this, new MouseEventArgs(); } else { DownButton_MouseDown(this, new MouseEventArgs(); }`